# Pull file from own git server

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have manage to setup git to push/pull files from local to my development server and vica versa.
Now my question is.
How can i after i delete a file localy, get that file back ?

When i do "git checkout"

It shows me:

```
D   helloworld.py
```

Or for example I want another Developer to work with me. How can he get the files from my Development server to his local computer ?

Comment: It seems you need to learn and understand git better. Start with [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/7976758). Git doesn't clone/push/pull files, git pushes/pulls trees of commits.

Comment: Im reading and learning at the moment. But I dont want to use Github so i have set it up on my server. But if developer2 now wants to sync with me. What should he do ? From a fresh clean pc, lets say a live version from ubuntu.

Comment: Please, do not use the same question to ask different things.

Comment: Its the same thing ? Get a file back that i delete ? Get all files from server for new developer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To delete a file localy use :**

```
rm -rf <filename>
```

**To delete a file from tracking use :**

```
git rm --cached <filename>
```

**For other developer to get files/repo :**

```
git clone user@server:/path/to/repo $HOME/<reponame>
git status
```